# How can I count the values of my number inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an form and I want the completed numbers to be added together. Nothing has to be done with the text and date input. I want to display the total of numbers in the span element with id "total".

```js
     function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("form");
    total = 0;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
        total = total + x.elements[i].value;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
    }
```

```html
<form id="form">
                  <tr>
                      <td><input type="text"></td>
                      <td><input type="number"></td>
                      <td><input type="date"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><input type="text"></td>
                      <td><input type="number"></td>
                      <td><input type="date"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td><input type="text"></td>
                      <td><input type="number"></td>
                      <td><input type="date"></td>
                  </tr>
          </form>
          </table>

        </div> <button class="trigger" onclick="myFunction()"> Bereken 
        studietempo </button>

      <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
          <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
          <p>Je hebt tot nu toe <span id="total"></span> ECTS behaald.</p>
          <p>Je huidige studietempo is:</p>
          <p>0 ECTS / maand.</p>
          <p>Op basis van dit studietempo heb je 15 maanden nodig voor je P</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop using this `for-loop`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.elements.length; i++) {...}
```

Parse the values as follow:

```
total = total + (isNaN(Number(x.elements[i].value)) ? 0 : Number(x.elements[i].value));
```

The first input in every TD is type of `text`, change to `number`

```
<td><input type="text"></td>
                 ^
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("form");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.elements.length; i++) {
    if (x.elements[i].type === 'number') {
      total += (isNaN(Number(x.elements[i].value)) ? 0 : Number(x.elements[i].value));
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <form id="form">

    <tr>
      <td><input type="number"></td>
      <td><input type="number"></td>
      <td><input type="date"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number"></td>
      <td><input type="number"></td>
      <td><input type="date"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number"></td>
      <td><input type="number"></td>
      <td><input type="date"></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>

<button class="trigger" onclick="myFunction()"> Bereken 
    studietempo </button>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!--span class="close-button">&times;</span>
    <p>Je hebt tot nu toe <span id="total"></span> ECTS behaald.</p>
    <p>Je huidige studietempo is:</p>
    <p>0 ECTS / maand.</p>
    <p>Op basis van dit studietempo heb je 15 maanden nodig voor je P</p-->
  </div>
</div>

<p>Demo</p>
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the total of numbers in the span element with id
>   "total".

You are trying to add up all the values as [Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) `x.elements` doesn't exclude `text` and `date`,

Use `querySelector` and `reduce`

```
var x = document.getElementById("form");
var total = Array.from( x.querySelectorAll( "[type='number']" ) )
                 .reduce( ( a, c ) => a + ( isNaN( c ) ? 0 + c ), 0 );
```

> I want to display the total of numbers in the span element with id
>   "total".

Now display this total

```
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: At least `1 think capacity` may be assumed to exist.

Comment: @Martijn  sorry didn't get you.